# How to configure HSTS in django

Tags: django, security, django-rest-framework, hsts, insecure-connection

I need to configure hsts in one of django app. I have read django doc and came to a point that if I set

```
SECURE_HSTS_SECONDS = 3600
SECURE_HSTS_INCLUDE_SUBDOMAINS = True
```

It will set hsts header on all request headers which it didn't
Additionally I got another key value

```
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')
```

That I need to set if my app is behind proxy.

I expect that on all of my django api request headers I see that hsts header.